# Best practise to Use NSURLSession to receive data from the server on the background(not on the main theard)

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsdata, nsurlrequest, nsurlsession

How to receive data from the server(the server echo's it as JSON) using NSURLSession in the most efficient way?

Example:

I'm trying to use Instagram's news feed as a save template. They show 10 images and then it will load 10 more(from the server) when you *pull down* and will not block the user (They receive/download it on the background - while the users are still using the app).

I want to do the same thing in the most efficient way. In my example the screen is frozen until data is fetched. How can I avoid blocking the user?

```
 var imgurl  = "http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg"
        var sessionConfog =     NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        var sessions : NSURLSession = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfog, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
        var getImageTask = sessions.downloadTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: imgurl)!, completionHandler: { (location : NSURL!, response : NSURLResponse!, error : NSError?) -> Void in
            var image : UIImage = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: location)!)!
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
               self.iamgeview.image = image
               let m = self.saveImage(image, path: self.documentsDirectory())
               println(m)
            })
        })
        getImageTask.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

I just noticed, you are NOT using NSURLSession correctly! In your completion block I see this:

```
var image : UIImage = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: location)!)!
```

DON'T do this. The NSURLSession download task already downloaded the data for you, you don't have to download it again with the method 'contentsOfURL'. Also that method is synchronous, and blocks the calling thread until the contents of the URL are loaded. You should never use that method to make network URLs.

What you need to do is implement the delegate methods for the download task so you get the data when it completes. An easier way for you is to use dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler - for that message, the completion handler receives the NSData from the response.

**END EDIT**

You are using NSURLSession correctly, but if you profile your app, most probably you will see that the most expensive operation here, and probably the one that blocks the UI thread, is:

```
let m = self.saveImage(image, path: self.documentsDirectory())
```

If you can save your image in a separate serial queue, then you'll see a big improvement.

Comment: But thats not what i need via NSURLSession , i need to do the most simple  thing that in someway i find very difficult to do : I have url that echos JSON array , I want to receive it using NSURLSession and "parse" it so i can use it , All of this should happen at the background(not foreground) , can you direct me to this?

Comment: NSURLSession API by definition is asynchronous. So you dont need to explicitly despatch this operation into a background thread. Avoid Creating multiple NSURLSession objects, use a single shared session and perform the Save to Gallery in background.

Comment: Im looking for answer for that as well.. Can you show sample code on how to retrieve DATA from server using it?

Comment: Hey, see my edit - I completely missed the part where you use contentsOfURL to get the NSData.